# Adding a new column in a Dataframe, with certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am very new to python,and have started working on text data.

I want add a column in the dataframe, compare it with a condition mentioned in a different column and fill it accordingly.

The dataset was of 10000 rows, I shortened it by taking out random sample of 2000 rows.

I want to include new column named " Review Sentiment " and fill the cells in it as  1 if review.rating is >3 and  0 if review.rating is =< 3.

Here is what I have tried.

**Code:**

```
Dataset = pd.read_csv('Datafiniti_Hotel_Reviews.csv')

Dataset_sample = Dataset.sample(n = 2000)
Dataset_sample.head()

i=0

for i in range(len(Dataset_sample.axes[0])):
            if(Dataset_sample['reviews.rating'] < 3):
                Dataset_sample.insert(len(Dataset_sample.axes[1],"Test",1))
            else:
                Dataset_sample.insert(len(Dataset_sample.axes[1],"Test",0))
```

Error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

[image]

Dataset: Extract from the dataset. Kindly help using these columns from the dataset. The logic would remain the same.

```
 ID   province reviews.rating 
 ----------------------------  
 1    CA             5
 7    ST             4
 3    DL             4
 6    YT             5
 5    JD             1
```

Comment: Please post a sample of data which can be copied, not an image.

Comment: `Dataset_sample['Test'] = Dataset_sample['reviews.rating'].lt(3).astype(int)`.

Comment: Also, you may want to do `Dataset_sample = Dataset.sample(n=2000).copy()`.

Comment: Please [provide a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `df.head(10).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard). [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely the question will be down-voted.  You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible.

Comment: I have put a snippet from dataset. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Data

dfBuses = pd.DataFrame({'size': [40,30], 'cost': [500,400]},
                      index = ['bus1', 'bus2'], columns=['size','cost']) 

print(dfBuses)

dfBuses['expensive']=[(row['cost']>=450)  for i,row in dfBuses.iterrows()]

print(dfBuses)
```

gives

```
      size  cost
bus1    40   500
bus2    30   400
      size  cost  expensive
bus1    40   500       True
bus2    30   400      False
```